# Accessing array within struct in a mapping using web3.js

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, struct, react

I have created a struct patient as follows, and a mapping of uint->patient.

```
struct patient {
    uint pId;
    string name;
    string phone;
    address payable owner;
    uint numRecords;
    uint[] cost;
    address[] uploader;
    string[] procedure;
    uint[] hospId;
    string[] doctorName;
    bool[] treated;
    string[] image;

}


mapping(uint => patient) public patients;
```

I am have created functions to insert data into the mapping.
However, when i try to read the data in reactjs using web3,

```
//REACTJS     
for (var i = 1; i <= patientCount; i++) {                                                 
            const patient = await container.methods.patients(i).call()
    }
```

the patient variable only contains the non array parts of the struct. 
i.e, only pId, name, phone, owner and numRecords is returned.

The value returned is

```
 {0: BigNumber, 1: "Name", 2: "1234567890", 3: "0x771D3a7C2d6C59D9030731a48D60D8296303fC06", 4: BigNumber, pId: BigNumber, name: "Name", phone: "1234567890", owner: "0x771D3a7C2d6C59D9030731a48D60D8296303fC06", numRecords: BigNumber}
0: BigNumber {_hex: "0x01", _ethersType: "BigNumber"}
1: "NAme"
2: "1234567890"
3: "0x771D3a7C2d6C59D9030731a48D60D8296303fC06"
4: BigNumber {_hex: "0x01", _ethersType: "BigNumber"}
name: "Name"
numRecords: BigNumber {_hex: "0x01", _ethersType: "BigNumber"}
owner: "0x771D3a7C2d6C59D9030731a48D60D8296303fC06"
pId: BigNumber {_hex: "0x01", _ethersType: "BigNumber"}
phone: "1234567890"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to return the whole struct you need to use the ABIEncoderV2 and define your own getter function

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract Foo {

  function getPatient(uint id) public view returns (patient memory) {
    return patients[id];
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, Thank you. Out of curiosity, is there any way to do this in a single funciton without using experimental features? Without using seperate funcitons for each parameter atleast..

Comment: @FarhadBharucha With current solc 0.6 you have to use experimental pragma and a separate function, perhaps in a future version they will make it the default choice but it is not possible yet.