# Access arrays from public struct mapping?

Tags: arrays, mapping, struct

I have this struct:

```
struct Amendment {
    string text;
    uint24 textColor;
    bool isRadialGradient;
    uint8[2] radialGradientCenterPct;
    uint16 linearGradientAngleDeg;
    uint24[2][11] gradientColors;
    uint messageId;
    uint inReplyToMessageId;
    address sender;
    address recipient;
    uint sentAt;
}
```

This mapping:

```
mapping(uint => Amendment) public amendmentMapping;
```

and this function:

```
function getAmendment(uint tokenId) public view returns (Amendment memory amendment) {
    return amendmentMapping[tokenId];
}
```

When I retrieve an Amendment via this function it works correctly. However, when I get an Amendment via the `amendmentMapping` directly the response does not include the arrays `radialGradientCenterPct` and `gradientColors`.

Ideally I would not have a separate getter, so I am curious whether this is a real limitation or whether I'm making a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your Solidity version, so sharing this might help. There are a couple questions with answers around this that might help:

- [Accessing array within struct in a mapping using web3.js](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83883/accessing-array-within-struct-in-a-mapping-using-web3-js)
- [Cannot retrieve uint Array from Struct in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118509/cannot-retrieve-uint-array-from-struct-in-solidity)

Comment: I am on 0.8.11 and I'm `pragma abicoder v2;` From those links it looks like I just need the getter unless something has been changed since the version in those answers

Comment: I found https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12384 which points to the docs https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions where it states that these will not be returned by the auto generated getters.